# React Query execute mutation after query is fetched

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Let's say I have a query, useFetchUser() and a mutation, useMutateUser(). When my component is rendered I want to fetch the current user and then execute the mutation after the query completion. So I have something like this:

```js
   const {data} = useFetchUser()
   const {mutate} = useMutateUser()

   useEffect(() => {
      if(data) {
        mutate() 
     }
   }, [data, mutate])
```

Now when I check in the network tab I see that the mutation starts while the query is still pending. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hard to say without knowing what the custom hooks are doing. since `data` will be `undefined` for as long as the query is initially loading, your condition prevents the mutation from running. Generally, I would put side effects into the `onSuccess` callback of the query.

Comment: You should debug with console logs inside the useEffect, you could console log isLoading and data fro example.

Answer (score 1):

You can send react-query options to your hook `useFetchUser()` in params and take advantage of `onSuccess` callback:

```
const useFetchUser = (options = {}) => {
    return useQuery(yourKey, () => fetchUser(), {...options})
}
```

And consume like this:

```
const {mutate} = useMutateUser()
const {data} = useFetchUser({onSuccess: mutate()})
```